# Как выделить част текста в TMemo?

Tags: delphi

Как в memo1 при двойном клике выделять не всю строку, а слова, от разделителя до разделителя? Разделители пробел и точка с запятой.

Например, есть текст

> hello;man van

кликнув по hello выделится hello, по man выделится man

Как это сделать?

Comment: Написать свой обработчик на событие `OnDoubleClick` для `Memo`.

Comment: Это понятно. Вопрос как именно сделать. Пытался по разному не получается.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Вероятно сложность не в том, чтобы подключить стандартный обработчик, а в том чтобы программно выделять текст.

Comment: Может автор вопроса уточнит в чем сложность, чтобы мы не догадывались?

Answer (score 1):

Обязательное условие выделения на экране, чтобы твой компонент `TMemo` обладал фокусом ввода, то есть в твоем случае `memo1.SetFocus`.

`TMemo` обладает такими же свойствами выделения текста, как и `TEdit`:

`SelStart`- имеет значение `integer` и задает номер символа, после которого будет стоять курсор;

`SelLength`- имеет значение `integer` и задает, сколько символов будет выделено;

`SelText` - имеет значение `string` и содержит выделенный текст.

Еще есть вариант нахождения позиции курсора через `CarePos` - имеет значение `TPoint`, и не сложно догадаться, что в `X` будет позиция курсора, в `Y` номер строки.

И все что тебе остается, это написать обработчик на событие `OnClick`.

Comment: `SelLenght` -> `SelLength`

Comment: @Igor исправил, спасибо, что заметил.